# Cmd on VBA code error " this object does not support this property or method"

Tags: shell, vba, excel, command-line, batch-file

here the code i used  i try to run cmdline to create the txt file and then import it into excel   it's keep saying "  this object does not support this property or method"

i dont know where to fix it i'm stuck now

```
Sub ImportTextFile()  
Dim rPaht As String
Dim rFileName As String
Dim rPaht1 As String
Dim rFileName1 As String

txtFpath = Sheet1.Range("a1").Value
Filesum = "type unixinv* > summary2.txt"

ChDrive "D"
RSP = Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC"), vbNormalFocus)


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
SendKeys "CD " & txtFpath & "{ENTER}", True


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
SendKeys Filesum & "{ENTER}", True


Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")
SendKeys "exit " & "{ENTER}", True

rPaht = Sheet1.Range("a1")
rFileName = Sheet1.Range("a2")
Sheet1.Cells.Clear
With Sheet4.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & rPaht & "\" & rFileName & ".txt", Destination:=Sheet1.Range("$A$4"))
    .Name = Sheet1.Range("C8").Value
    .TextFilePlatform = 874
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ":"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Sheet1.Range("a1") = rPaht
Sheet1.Range("a2") = rFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you view the code in the VBA IDE and tell us where the error fires?

Comment: i did it around after all sendkey and cmd work is done

Comment: .Refreshtype = xlOverwriteCells
        .TextFilePlatform = 874

around here somewhere

Comment: i found it 

it is    .refreshtype  

it is very important if i dont have this line my  text file will start to push everything to right side after import

Comment: if you solved your problem, you may want to post your solution as an answer or close the post

Answer (score 2):

`Sendkeys` are highly unreliable. What you are trying can be easily achieved without sending keys to the command window after opening it. See the below code. It cuts down all excessive code.

in the below example, I am demostrating on how to export `DIR` to `summary2.txt` Change as applicable.

```
Sub ImportTextFile()
    Dim txtFpath As String, Filesum As String
    Dim RSP

    'Ex: txtFpath = "D:\MyFolder"
    txtFpath = Sheet1.Range("a1").Value

    Filesum = "cmd.exe /c Type " & txtFpath & "summary2.txt"

    RSP = Shell(Filesum, vbHide)

    rPaht = Sheet1.Range("a1")
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```